# Should I sample or compute the innovation term in the recursive estimation OLS algorithm applied to time-series data?

Tags: forecasting, least-squares, error, recursive-model

I have time-series data $\{Z_{[t]}\} = Z_t, Z_{t-1}, ..., Z_1$ of length $L$, and I would like to estimate a model for the $\{Z_{[t]}\}$ so I can forecast $Z_{t+1}$ as a function of a number of its past values.

$$
Z_{t+1} = \sum_{i = 0}^t \phi_{t-i}Z_{t-1} + \epsilon \quad \quad [1]
$$

where $\epsilon$ has a distribution $D$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Once $Z_{t+1}$ is computed, I'd like to append it to the data vector $\{Z\}$ to re-estimate the parameters $\phi \in \Phi$.

Suppose I decide to estimate a model with two parameters for $\{Z_{[t]}\}$. Using OLS, I could do

$$
\boldsymbol{\phi} = (\boldsymbol{X}^\top \boldsymbol{X})^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^\top y \quad \quad [2]
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\phi} \in \mathbb{R}^2, \boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{(L-2)\times 2}$ is a matrix of lagged ${Z}$ values, and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{(L-2)}$ is the vector $\{Z_{t},Z_{t-1}, ..., Z_{t - L + 2}\}$. To help visualize what I mean, suppose the time series has only 6 data points. I could write $y$ and $\boldsymbol{X}$ respectively as

$$
y = \begin{pmatrix} Z_6 \\ Z_5 \\ Z_4 \\ Z_3 \end{pmatrix}
\\
\\
\boldsymbol{X} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
Z_5 & Z_4 \\
Z_4 & Z_3 \\
Z_3 & Z_2 \\
Z_4 & Z_3 \\
Z_2 & Z_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

With $y$ and $\boldsymbol{X}$, I obtain $\{\phi_1, \phi_2\}$ and forecast $Z_7$ using $Z_6, Z_5$ as input and an innovation $\epsilon$ (noise) term.

> **Question 1: What's the recommended way to sample $\epsilon$?**

So far, I have used the fitted model to calculate the error $\epsilon_{TD}$ on the training data $Z_6, ..., Z_3$. I checked the error's mean and variance and visualized its distribution with a histogram. Using a qqplot, I assessed the likelihood of the data being normally distributed. If it looks "normal enough", I'd sample $\epsilon$ from a normal distribution such that $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\text{mean}(\epsilon_{TD}), \text{var}(\epsilon_{TD}))$.

> **Question 2: Is the normal distribution the ideal distribution for the error? Or is it OK to have a different distribution?**

I know that in the OLS distribution, it's expected that the error show no temporal correlation and display a normal-distribution behavior.

Once I have $Z_7$, I can append it to $y$ and re-estimate the model parameters. In searching for a way to update the parameters without having to compute the normal equation, Equation [1](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119815068), again, I looked up "recursive estimation with OLS".

I found a vast literature in the field of System's Identification and Estimation, and one recurrent fact caught my attention. As seen in Powell's writings [here (pg. 165-167)](https://castle.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Powell-Sequential_Decision_Analytics_NOW_March4-2022-1.pdf) and [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119815068) as well as in [Mendel's book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&q=discrete%20techniques%20of%20parameter%20estimation%20mendel&btnG=),  it is assumed that a new "measurement" or "signal" will "come"/"arrive"/"be read", and that allows for the calculation of the innovation term: $\epsilon_{t+1} = Z_{t+1} - Z_t$. **As far as I understand, this approach won't work with me.** I can't expect a new "measurement" to "arrive"; I have to forecast it. The innovation or noise term is calculated from data instead of being generated from a distribution.

> **Question 3: Is the generation of the innovation a legitimate way to go about this?**

My questions mostly stem from the fact that in the examples I read, the data were not time-dependent. In my case, however, the data at a time $t$ will depend on past values.